# How do I use the webcam on my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, webcam

I have a Core i3 model of the dell laptop.There is a webcam placed on top of the laptop.It becomes usable automatically when I am trying to place a pic on some social media site or something.How do I use it to take pictures when I want? How do I start this camera? There is no option in my system that allows me to use this.I could'nt find any software for using this.Please help me.I have a windows 7 installed on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install something like [Photo booth](http://photo-booth-for-windows-7.en.softonic.com/)

Comment: please change your answer so it becomes as constructive as possible. Also, is there any reason to use that particular software?

Comment: No, there is no reason to use that particular software. I said "something like".

Answer (score 1):

If you type your service tag code into the dell website under the support / drivers section you'll be able to download the utilities that normally ship with your laptop.  On there will be the software for controlling the webcam.  If I recall correctly the dell webcam software lets you put virtual hats / masks on etc.